# How to return private char array from member function?

Tags: c++

How can i return the private char "n" from the member function to the main function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class TEST
{
    char n[10];
public:
    char getname()
    {
        cout<<"what's your name?:";
        cin.getline(n,10);
        return n;
    }
};
int main()
{   char name[10];
    TEST obj;
    name[10]=obj.getname();
    cout<<"Name :"<<name;
}
```

Comment: How about a `std::string`, or is there an arbitrary restriction against it?

Comment: Do you really think it matters that it is private?

Comment: You can't return any array from any function, nor can you assign to an array. Also, `name[10]` is an out-of-bounds operation. There's a list of good books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @juanchopanza I actually don't really know... maybe I need to use a pointer or something but I don't know how.

Comment: @KarWai So make it public and see? Problem solving 101.

Comment: Your first problem is that `n` is not a `char`. It's a `char[10]`. Your use of "`name[10]`" makes me reckon you think the name is "name[10]" and the type is "char". It's not!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit alright i think i understand it, sorry if it's a silly question I'm still new to c++ hahaha... thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private or public is not matter. your problem is return `char` instead of `char*`.

I suggest you to use string instead of char array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class TEST
{
    char n[10];
public:
    char* getname()
    {
        cout<<"what's your name?:";
        cin.getline(n,10);
        return n;
    }
};
int main()
{   
    char* name;
    TEST obj;
    name = obj.getname();
    cout<<"Name :"<<name;
}
```

Comment: Won't compile for `name = obj.getname();`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I test it, it is correct, you must be use pointer instead of array in main function.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz: No, it is not correct. [You are violating `const`-correctness](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad4e2afdd0c33553). If your compiler accepts this, it is broken.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes it is my distraction, I correct it. ;)

Comment: Next time please do not outright lie about whether or not you have tested the answers you provide.

Comment: @songyuanyao yes you right I correct it, I test without const. and write with const here, I am sorry for this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was not lying, simply because of the distraction test code that different from written code here. From now on I will concentrate more

Answer (score 1):

> How can i return the private char "n" from the member function to the main function?

You can return pointer to first element of character array which is under `private` label in your class. For it, you need to change the function definition of your `getname` function to `char *getname()`.

Also, i would like to point out some error you have made in `main` function. Have a look at my version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class TEST
{
   char n[10];
public:
    char* getname()
    {
        cout<<"what's your name?:";
        cin.getline(n,10);
        return n;
   }  
};
int main()
{   
   TEST obj;
   char *name = obj.getname();
   cout<<"Name :"<<name;
}
```

But it is not a good practice to return a reference or pointer to private member of your class. Exposing any of your internal implementation details is potentially a violation of encapsulation. Instead of providing access to private data members of a class, you can define member functions which will perform desired operation on your private data members.

Also, try to avoid using `using namespace`.